# SQL query isn't working with PostgreSQL command

Tags: postgresql, psql

I run the sql command on SQL Shell for PostgreSQL. However, it isn't working.

I don't know what's wrong.

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: You need to terminate **every** SQL Command with `;` not just some. But you don't need a `;` for the `psql` meta commands like `\d`

Comment: Also you may see by the content of terminal characters if you are in the first line of query or you are continuing query from previous line(s) (mydb=# vs mydb-#)

Comment: Under `\?`, I do read `\g with no arguments is equivalent to a semicolon`.  So, in stead of the semi colon, you can also use `\g`.

Comment: The semi colon and \g isn't fact. However, query isn't working properly.
INSERT INTO users(name, age, birthday) VALUES('Sabbir', 27, '2000-10-02')

It is returning "Insert 0 1" however it isn't working